# Story about robots turning humans into birds

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for a short story I read many years ago about robots which, in their attempt to make people happy, and knowing that people had fantasies about flying, one day capture all people and turn them into birds.

Comment: Can you give a more precise time than "many years ago" or more details?  Our guide at https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/ may give you more ideas on what type of details we are looking for in identification questions.

Comment: I'm somewhat unclear about the date of the story. I read it probably in the 1970's either in an anthology or in a magazine.